# How to have DataGrid to Fill Up the Blank Space in Window in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am working on a project in WPF. In Which my requirement is to attach my DataGrid at the bottom of the Window, so that if the users will Restore Down or Maximize the window or change the size of the window, the DataGrid will should not go beyond the main window in terms of height and should resize automatically and scroll bars should appear view the data. In the code given below the DataGrid is only displays the data available for example if there are only 2 rows to display it will show only 2 row in the datagrid and remaining users can see the background and if the data is having 50 60 rows the data grid will go beyond the main window and users cannot see all the rows in the Data Grid.

My Requirement
Datagrid Height should not go beyond than the available space in the Main Window. 
If there are no rows to display in the DataBase then DataGrid Should show Empty Rows or Simply Gray Space.

```
<StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Margin="40 50 0 0" Text="Label1:" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Medium" />
        <ComboBox x:Name="CustomerList" Margin="15 40 0 0" Padding="7" Width="300" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Medium" Cursor="Hand">
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Margin="25 30 0 0" Text="Label2" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Medium" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="54"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="AppName" Margin="15 30 0 0" Padding="7" Width="230" Background="LightCyan" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Medium" />
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">          
        <TextBox x:Name="Tenure" Margin="20 30 0 0" Padding="7" Width="170" Background="LightCyan" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Medium" />          
    </StackPanel>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1000"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0">

               <TextBlock Margin="25 30 0 0" Text="Label2.:" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Medium" Width="80" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0">                    
                <Button x:Name="Add_btn" Content="Add Data" Width="120" Padding="12" Background="Transparent" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Medium" Margin="15 30 0 0" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Click="Add_btn_Click" Cursor="Hand"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Image Source="C:\Users\Asim Abbas\Source\Icons\Upload1.png" Height="90" Width="90" Margin="0 25 0 0" MouseLeftButtonDown="Image_MouseLeftButtonDown" Cursor="Hand">
                <Image.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect/>
                </Image.Effect>
            </Image>

            <TextBlock Margin="20,5,0,0" Text="Upload" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Medium" />

        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

This is The Point Where Thing Gets Ugly - The Data Is Continuing from Above

```
    <DataGrid 
        DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
        x:Name="Grid"
        Margin="0 20 0 0"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        CanUserAddRows="False"
        CanUserDeleteRows="False"
        ColumnHeaderHeight="60"
        CanUserResizeColumns="False"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
        CanUserReorderColumns="False"
        CanUserResizeRows="False"
        CanUserSortColumns="False"
        RowBackground="LightCyan"
        RowHeight="30"
        HorizontalGridLinesBrush="LightGray"
        Width="Auto"            
        IsReadOnly="True"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
        FontSize="11"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        FontWeight="Medium"
        VerticalGridLinesBrush="LightGray" 
        BorderBrush="FloralWhite"
        MouseDoubleClick="LCGrid_MouseDoubleClick">

        <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value=".5,.5,.5,.5"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="FloralWhite"/>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>

        <DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRowHeader">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="25"/>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Medium"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="FloralWhite"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>

        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                            <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                                <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Col1}" Header="Col 1" Width="150"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Col1}" Header="Col2" Width="60">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Col1, StringFormat={}{0:dd-MMM-yy}}" Header="Col 3" Width="80"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Col1}" Header="Col3" Width="80"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Col1}" Header="Col 4" Width="250"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Col1}" Header="Col5" Width="80"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Col1, StringFormat=N2}" Header="LC Value" Width="100">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Col1, StringFormat=N2}" Header="Col6" Width="100">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Col1, StringFormat=N2}" Header="Col 7" Width="100">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Col1, StringFormat=N2}" Header="Col8" Width="100">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Col1, StringFormat=N2}" Header="Col9" Width="100">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Col1, StringFormat={}{0:dd-MMM-yy}}" Header="Col10" Width="80"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Col1, StringFormat={}{0:dd-MMM-yy}}" Header="Col11" Width="80"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Col1}" Header="Col12" Width="250"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Col1, StringFormat=N0}" Header="Col13" Width="80">

                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Col1, StringFormat=N0}" Header="Col 14" Width="80">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Col1}" Header="Col 15" Width="150"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Col1}" Header="Col 16" Width="150"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Col1}" Header="Col 17" Width="200"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Col1}" Header="Col 18" Width="80"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Col1}" Header="Col 19" Width="100"/>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

</StackPanel>
```

Comment: You need to learn how to [use panels for layout](http://wpftutorial.net/layoutproperties.html).  This fixed-size layout with controls haphazardly positioned with `Margin` is extremely fragile.

Answer (score 0):

in a short answer you have to use a `Grid` with `RowDefinition Height="*"` - your row will have a relative height

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>  <!-- fit componets size -->
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>     <!-- relative size -->
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <StackPanel>
             ..........
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
                  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

            ...............
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks but It didnt Worked. When the Data is Loaded, DataGrid went way beyond the Window Size / Height. I have around 4000 rows in my data. When the Data is loaded I want the DataGrid Height not to go beyond the remaining height of the window and User should be able to scroll within the DataGrid.

Comment: @AsimAbbas added ScrollViewer to ther DataGrid

Comment: This works if you do it right.  Everything _above_ the `DataGrid` should go into the _first_ row (where Celso put the `StackPanel`).  The `DataGrid` itself goes in the _second_ row.  The `Grid` should be the root layout panel.  You **cannot** make the grid a descendant of a `StackPanel`, or it won't work right.

Comment: I am doing exactly the way it is described by Celso above, In the design environment in VS the DataGrid shows exactly the way I want but when the program runs there are no rows loaded, when i am clicking a the Show Data Button it loads the data from the SQL and since there are many rows in the DB the DataGrid goes out of the window and i cannot vertically scroll. My Desktop Res. is 1920 x 1080 and prog. is run maximized. The Prog. Runs in a mainpage where i have a frame and frame is loading a page where there is DataGrid and other Stuff. Page size is d:DesignHeight="620" d:DesignWidth="1200"

Comment: try remove this: `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` `VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"`    it is better to first remove all your style and see if it is ok, then it will help the style gradually to see if there is something wrong, put a simple datagrid without this lot of things you put and see if it is ok